# Change part of "src" attribute of iframe with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I actually need to disable autoplay on a vimeo iframe embed on a drupal 6 website.

I can't change this settings in the embedmedia module, so I need to use jQuery to do this.

This is the original "src" vimeo content:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/69431566?fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" style="height: 23vw; width: 100vw;"></iframe>
```

I override the height and width attributes with jQuery already.

So I try to do the same for "src" but my code replace the "src" content:

```
$("#media-vimeo-1 iframe").attr('src','autoplay=0');
```

How can I preserve the other part of src content and only change the autoplay setting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the old `src`, replace the desired parameters, and then change the `src`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oldSrc = $("#media-vimeo-1 iframe").attr("src"); //Get the src of the iframe
  var newSrc = oldSrc.replace("autoplay=1", "autoplay=0"); //Replace "autoplay=1" by "autoplay=0"
  
  $("#media-vimeo-1 iframe").attr("src", newSrc); //Change the src attr to the new value
  
  console.log("Old Src: " + oldSrc);
  console.log("New Src: " + newSrc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="media-vimeo-1">
  <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/69431566?fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" style="height: 23vw; width: 100vw;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [second parameter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to `attr` can be a function that processes the old value to get a new value:

```
$("#media-vimeo-1 iframe").attr('src', function (index, oldSrc) {
    return oldSrc.replace('autoplay=1', 'autoplay=0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example youre just setting the `src` attribute to be `autoplay=0`
What you realistically want to do is grab the current value, replace a value within the string and reassign the value.

Example (There are better ways to do this):

```
var link = $("iframe").attr('src');
link = link.replace('autoplay=1', 'autoplay=0');
$("iframe").attr('src', link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help you.

```
var src = $('iframe').attr('src'); <br>
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(src); <br>
searchParams.set('autoplay','0'); <br>
var newParams = searchParams.toString(); <br>
$('iframe').attr('src', decodeURIComponent(newParams)); <br>
```

Source code: 
https://github.com/sendeveloper/stackoverflow/tree/master/javascript_src_autoplay